# Sitecore Lucene indexing - file not found exception using advanced database crawler

Tags: lucene, sitecore, filenotfoundexception

I'm having a problem with Sitecore/Lucene on our Content Management environment, we have two Content Delivery environments where this isn't a problem. I'm using the Advanced Database Crawler to index a number of items of defined templates. The index is pointing to the master database.

The index will remain 'stable' for a few hours or so, and then in the logs I will start to see this error appearing. Along with if I try and open a Searcher.

```
ManagedPoolThread #17 16:18:47 ERROR Could not update index entry. Action: 'Saved', Item: '{9D5C2EAC-AAA0-43E1-9F8D-885B16451D1A}'
Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Message: Could not find file 'C:\website\www\data\indexes\__customSearch\_f7.cfs'.
Source: Lucene.Net
   at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentInfos.FindSegmentsFile.Run()
   at Sitecore.Search.Index.CreateReader()
   at Sitecore.Search.Index.CreateSearcher(Boolean close)
   at Sitecore.Search.IndexSearchContext.Initialize(ILuceneIndex index, Boolean close)
   at Sitecore.Search.IndexDeleteContext..ctor(ILuceneIndex index)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.DeleteItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.UpdateItem(Item item)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.IndexingProvider.UpdateItem(HistoryEntry entry, Database database)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.IndexingProvider.UpdateIndex(HistoryEntry entry, Database database)
```

From what I read this can be due to an update on the index whilst there is an open reader, and when a merge operation happens the reader will still have a reference to the deleted segment, or something to that avail (I'm not an expert on Lucene).

I have tried a few things with no success. Including sub classing the Sitecore.Search.Index object and overriding CreateWriter(bool recreate) to change the merge scheduler/policy and tweaking the merge factor. See below.

```
protected override IndexWriter CreateWriter(bool recreate)
{
      IndexWriter writer = base.CreateWriter(recreate);
      LogByteSizeMergePolicy policy = new LogByteSizeMergePolicy();
      policy.SetMergeFactor(20);
      policy.SetMaxMergeMB(10);
      writer.SetMergePolicy(policy);
      writer.SetMergeScheduler(new SerialMergeScheduler());
      return writer;
}
```

When I'm reading the index I call SearchManager.GetIndex(Index).CreateSearchContext().Searcher and when I'm done getting the documents I need I call .Close() which I thought would've been sufficient.

I was thinking I could perhaps try overriding CreateSearcher(bool close) as well, to ensure I'm opening a new reader each time, which I will give a go after this. I don't really know enough about how Sitecore handles Lucene, its readers/writers?

I also tried playing around with the UpdateInterval value in the web config to see if that would help, alas it didn't.

I would greatly appreciate anyone who a) knows of any kind of situations in which this could occur, and b) any potential advice/solutions, as I'm starting to bang my head against a rather large wall :)

We're running Sitecore 6.5 rev111123 with Lucene 2.3.

Thanks,

James.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like Lucene freaks out when you try to re-index something that is in the process of being indexed already. To verify that, try the following:

- Set the `updateinterval` of your index to a really high value (8 hours).
- Then, stop the `w3wp.exe` and delete the index.
- After deleting the index try to rebuild the index in Sitecore and wait for this to finish.
- Test again and see if this occurs.

If this doesn't occur anymore it will be the `updateinterval` set too low which causes your index (that is probably still being constructed) to be overwritten with a new one (that won't be finished either) causing your `segments.gen` file to contain the wrong index information.

This `.gen` file will point your `indexreader` to what segments are part of your index and is recreated after index rebuilding.

That's why I suggest to try to disable the updates for a large amount of time and to rebuild it manually.